# ReflectionException Class � does not exist Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, symfony4

i have this problem on my localhost idk what happens with this error ? it appear suddenly , please help !

[image]

Comment: It looks like you added a definition of some class somewhere by accident, hence the class name "�". Try searching your code for a typo?

Comment: I already search but nothing with that strange name D:

Comment: You could also debug the code using tools like `xdebug` https://xdebug.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the error, its Xampp idk what happend but when i restart my apache service my project works like a charm. So the solution is

> Restart apache